# Simple form not sending parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

This is my form

```
    <%= simple_form_for '', url: temperature2_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :search, collection: @vehicles, :label_method => :objectno, :label => 'Vehiculo',  :selected => params[:search] %>
        <%= f.button :submit, value: "Buscar",:name => nil%>
    <% end %>
```

If I print the on the console p @vehicles, you can see that there are values

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id: nil, objectno: "Carlos">, #<Message id: nil, objectno: "HLPN">, #<Message id: nil, objectno: "024">, #<Message id: nil, objectno: "HLMAW">]>
```

However, when I select record from the collection @vehicles the URL does not contain a vehicle:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/temperature2?search=
```

I was expecting

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/temperature2?search=Carlos
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I think you need name attribute in the input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing `value` properties in your generated HTML form. I guess you need to change the `label_method` to `value_method` in your form.

```
<%= f.input :search, collection: @vehicles, :value_method => :objectno, :label => 'Vehiculo',  :selected => params[:search] %>
```